# insert query for enum datatype column .. values are grabbed from selected checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, enums

> hello,
>
> i have a email subscription form,on which we are entering email address  and a group of categories of which the subscriber wants the coupon.
>   categories are like Travel,gifts,electronics,food,health and beauty etc. . on form these categories are placed using check-box. user checks them and has to get only checked category related coupons.

i used 'enum' data-type for saving those category list; set list using enum editor;changed check-box values to respected category name but now stuck on insert query.
or is their any other efficient wat to do this.

> waiting.. thanx
>
> ```html
> <div class="InputOuterDiv">
> <div class="EnquiryInpTitle"><strong>Enter Email Address:</strong></div>
> <div class="EnquiryInputBox">
> <input name="" type="text" class="EnquiryInput" />
> </div>
> </div>
> <div class="InputOuterDiv">
> <div class="CategoryLabelTitle"><strong>Select  Category:</strong></div> 
> <div class="CategoryTitle"><input type="checkbox" value="Travel" />  Travel</div>
> <div class="CategoryTitle"><input type="checkbox" value="Shopping" /> Shopping</div>
> <div class="CategoryTitle"><input type="checkbox" value="Electronics" /> Electronics</div>
> <div class="CategoryTitle"><input type="checkbox" value="Entertainment" /> Entertainment</div>
> <div class="CategoryTitle"><input type="checkbox" value="Food" /> Food & Drink </div>
> <div class="CategoryTitle"><input type="checkbox" value="Gift" /> Gift flowers</div>
> <div class="CategoryTitle"><input type="checkbox" value="Health"/> Health & Beauty</div>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide your checkboxes with a name, like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="datatypes[]" value="travel" />
```

... and so on.

This will provide you with an array on submit that will contain each value that was clicked.

You won't be able to use an `enum` field for these values because you won't have any control over which combination of values are chosen.  You're better off using a `varchar` field and `join()`-ing the array values before you insert them into your table.

```
<?php 
$dt = $_GET["datatypes"];  // this will be an array....
// check your array like this...
print "<pre>".print_r($dt,true)."</pre>";
// now insert it.
$query = "insert into my_table (datatypes) values ('".join(',',$dt)."')";
mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: dont use mysql its depricated use mysqli or pdo instead http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: yes, mysql_ funcs are deprecated.  i was simply writing that as an example of how it would work.  i recommend using PDO

Comment: thanks ... took your tip and its running also using PDO now.:) @rkstar